# In “我只喜歡你一個” what does the "一個" do?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

If I were to translate "I only like you" I'd say

> 我只喜歡你
>
> Wǒ zhǐ xǐ huan nǐ

However I have seen the following

> 我只喜歡你一個
>
> Wǒ zhǐ xǐ huan nǐ yī ge

Translated as

> I like you alone

What is the effect of adding the "一個"?

Comment: This effect is already clear in English, no?

Comment: Or if you want to be fancy with the translation: "You are my one and only true love". Just don't use it in real life. Trust me, it has never worked for me lol...

Comment: "I like you alone" isn't good english which threw me off. I had a minor thought that it might mean "I only like you when you're on your own"

Comment: I've heard "I like you and you alone" but not sure how authentic it is in English...

Comment: @NS.X Replace "alone" with "only" should do the trick. Alone just doesn't sound right to me (but of course it can be understood).

Comment: @NS.X. agreed with your first comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is there for emphasis.

The two sentences have similar meanings, while the one with "一個" has more emphasis on that you are the **ONLY** one that I like. It can be used to transfer stronger emotion.

Comment: this is the answer I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just as NS.X said in comment, your translation is already clear

> 我只喜歡你一個
>
> I like you alone

Or we can translate as follow

> You are the only one I love / like.